# Visual Basic failing to load XML because of undefined entity

Tags: xml, vb.net, xslt

I'm trying to use VBA to run an XSLT transformation on XML inputs. The XSLT works just fine when I run it in Oxygen (using Saxon), but the intent is to package it up into a 'one click' executable that people without Oxygen licenses can use.

My problem is that the visual basic chokes and dies at the DOMDocument.load step.

Here's a sample of the code:

```
Dim inDoc = New MSXML.DOMDocument
inDoc.validateOnParse = False
inDoc.resolveExternals = False
inDoc.load([filepath here])
```

And here's a representative bit of XML:

```
<permissions>
    <copyright-statement>&copy; 2017 Copyright Owner</copyright-statement>
</permissions>
```

It fails with "Reference to undefined entity 'copy'."

I have no control over the incoming XML -- I have to work with what I'm given -- so is there a way to force the load method to stop checking the content of the file?

Comment: &copy; is a valid named entity in HTML but not in XML, its presence makes the document unparsable.  One option is to preprocess the string and replace the entity with its symbol (saving as utf8) or replacing it with a character code escape &#char_code

Comment: Also, consider adding an [`<!Entity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256483(v=vs.110).aspx) possibly during XSLT step. See also [add entities in XML](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-entities/index.html) IBM reads.

Comment: `Dim inDoc = New MSXML.DOMDocument` is not valid VBA code. If you're coding with Microsoft Visual Studio, you're writing VB.NET and should definitely consider looking into what LINQ-to-XML can do for you. If you're coding with an editor from 1999 embedded in a Microsoft Office application, you're writing VBA code and what you posted can't possibly compile. Please tag your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a method that works based on Alex K's suggestion. It feels rather crude but it does what I need it to do, so maybe helpful to other people working with imperfect inputs?

First read the whole XML file into a string, then run the following:

```
inString = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(inString)
inString = Replace(inString, "&lt;", "<")
inString = Replace(inString, "&gt;", ">")
inString = Replace(inString, "&quot;", """")

inDoc.loadXML(inString)
outString = inDoc.transformNode(xsl)
outString = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(outString)
```

And then write outString to a file.